# Правильно ли стоит запятая перед местоимением "который"?

Tags: пунктуация

Волейболисты тренировались, который час подряд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нет, не нужна**. Здесь возможна только интонационная запятая, но в нейтральном тексте она выглядела бы совершенно неоправданной.

Давайте исходить из грамматики. "Который" здесь выступает в роли местоименного числительного (ср. "тренировались десятый час подряд") и выражает усиление (дословно: "час с большим номером").

Таким образом, "который" не является союзным словом, не вводит ни придаточное, ни даже обособляемый оборот. Думаю, и то и другое достаточно очевидно: придаточного здесь нет потому, что нет ни одного слова на роль главного члена, а что касается оборота, то подобные конструкции со словом "который" крайне редки вообще и требуют как минимум наличия управляющего слова ("стул, который слева"), ничего похожего у нас нет.

Answer (score 1):

Волейболисты тренировались /который час подряд.

**Нет паузы в простом предложении, устойчивое выражение** "который час подряд" является обстоятельственным оборотом со значением "много часов подряд".

Сравнить: Волейболисты тренировались /много часов подряд.

Местоимение КОТОРЫЙ здесь не является союзным словом в сложном или осложненном предложении, перед которым обычно ставится запятая.

Пример: Из окна который час подряд я гляжу на месиво златое...

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (почему местоименное прилагательное КОТОРЫЙ приобрело значение "не первый уже, не один").**

Из словаря Кузнецова:

**КОТОРЫЙ,**

**I. местоим. прил.** 1. Обозначает вопрос **о порядке выбора** предметов; какой именно? какой из нескольких? В к. вагон садиться?  2. Обозначает вопрос **о порядке предмета при счёте;** какой по порядку, по счёту? К. час? 3. **Не первый уже, не один.** К. день ждём, а они всё не возвращаются. К. раз я тебе уже это говорю!

**II. союзн. сл.** 1. Связывает определит. придат. предложение с главным, определяя в нём какое-л. существительное или местоимение. Вот те люди, к-ые спасли вас. Дом, в котором я жил, перестроен. 2. Связывает дополнит. придат. предложение с главным. Я забыл, в котором году это было.

**А действительно, почему?** Уж очень отличается это значение от других значений этого слова. Мне лично кажется, что здесь ч**то-то вроде риторического вопроса (который, какой по счету),**  окончательно утратившего свою вопросительную природу. Тогда почему бы не считать его устойчивым выражением или найти другое объяснение этому факту? **Но только не твердить: здесь всё ясно, понятно, нам это неинтересно, поэтому и вас это не должно интересовать.**

Comment: А пауза при чем? А "устойчивое выражение" при чем? Ужас какой... Автор-то почему сомневается? Потому что *слышит здесь паузу*. А вы говорите: паузы нет. А она говорит: а мне кажется, есть! Тупик? В этом и порочность вашего "интонационного" подхода, и плохо, что вы этого не понимаете.

Comment: Вам русскую грамматику объяснять  - все равно что  дошкольнику высшую математику.  "Который час подряд" - это обстоятельственный оборот со значением времени в ПРОСТОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ (сравнить: Волейболисты тренировались /много часов подряд). Но оборот этот НЕСТАНДАРТНЫЙ, так как включает местоимение КОТОРЫЙ.  В данном случае это местоимение союзным словом  не является, тем не менее всем хочется поставить перед ним запятую,  а вот этого делать как раз не надо.

Comment: И элементарную информацию о  простом предложении пора бы Вам усвоить. Простое предложение состоит из двух фраз, пауза там не обозначается, но переход от восходящей интонации к нисходящей можно ошибочно принять за паузу, что многие частенько делают. Вот такое сочетание особенностей и послужило причиной вопроса.

Comment: Именно, именно. "Переход от восходящей к нисходящей" и прочая заумь, которая (союзное слово!) нужна разве что студентам старших курсов филфака, ну, и еще ученым-филологам. Но здесь вопросов не задают ни те, ни другие! Вопросы здесь на сто процентов школьные, и эта ваша "восходящая и нисходящая" ну совсем ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

**который**
местоимение,  неопределенное ( обычно в сочетании с сущ.: "раз", "день", "год" и т.п. ) - ***уже много, не первый, не один***.

Стаканы **в который раз** наполнялись вином (*Бабаевский, Кавалер Золотой Звезды*).
Стоят у переправы **который год** нескошенные травы (*С.Васильев, Портрет партизана*).

Снег идет не переставая **который час подряд**.
[Испытано на себе](http://belchas.by/news/ispytano-na-sebe-odin-den-iz-zhizni-rabotnikov-stolichnoi-dorozhno-kommunalnoi-sluzhby.html)

Часто употребляется с усилительными частицами ***уже ( уж ), вот уже ( вот уж )*:**
Я любовался ими **вот уже который час подряд.**
[Эра Мориарти](https://books.google.ee/books?id=D9t9CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4&source=bl&ots=y9oDOcGCHb&sig=tAl_-JzHkWdU_s1LrMPqVaYXs9w&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-3NLIkv_SAhWqIpoKHdNnAe84ChDoAQgiMAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4&f=false)

... **Вот уже который час подряд** я безуспешно пытаюсь подвести вас к совершенно неожиданной мысли...
[Секретный рейд адмирала Брэда](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ajj9CAAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4&source=bl&ots=XsAFRjlH7_&sig=Jxcx2FOYcHT7WEp5SBIwx9_CO0Q&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBiPftlP_SAhXFBZoKHaSFA0I4FBDoAQgWMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4&f=false)

Так что запятая в *Вашем* предложении не нужна.